# Did I stumble upon a pattern in a random generator - or did I get something insanely rare?

Tags: python, math, random

While I was testing whether Python lists keep iterating if you add new items to the list, I stumbled upon a situation that I found rather remarkable, especially if you do the maths. My code looked like this;

```py
import random

listy = [1]

for _ in listy:
    if random.random() > 0.25:
        listy.append(100)

print(listy)
print(len(listy))
```

Usually, the lists ended up not being so big - most were below eight, and one was about 12. When I kept spamming the terminal with the program for about 20-30-ish times, I stumbled upon a list with 35 elements.

```
[1, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
35
```

If you do the maths, the chance of getting this, is so astronomically large that I'm almost starting to doubt there's a different reason I got this humongous list; is this an example of when a pseudo-random generator is really pseudo-random? Am I miscalculating something? Did I in fact stumble upon an event that is absurdly rare?

I know this isn't a traditional question, and ironically, the whole point of this question is that one isn't supposed to be able to recreate this event.

*Edit:* Yup, I was insanely stupid. I intended the list to expand with a 75% chance, but calculated the odds for when it would expand with a 25% chance. At 75%, this event isn't that rare. At 25%, it IS nearly impossible.

Comment: Shuffle a deck of cards.  Now calculate the chance it comes out in that order.

Comment: Oh wow that's a _really_ good analogy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing weird about that at all.

I added a couple lines to your script to see how long of string of 100s you might see:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for trials in range(10000):
    listy = [1]
    for _ in listy:
        if random.random() > 0.25:
            listy.append(100)
    counter[len(listy)] += 1
print(counter)
```

I ran it and got

```
Counter({1: 2488, 2: 1907, 3: 1386, 4: 1084, 5: 786, 6: 623, 7: 464, 8: 322, 9: 262, 10: 164, 11: 127, 12: 100, 13: 66, 14: 61, 15: 48, 16: 26, 17: 24, 18: 12, 22: 9, 19: 8, 21: 8, 20: 7, 26: 3, 23: 3, 24: 3, 28: 2, 25: 2, 27: 2, 33: 1, 31: 1, 35: 1})
```

Yep, a 35 straight up.

Maybe not as quickly as you did, but it can for sure happen.

Comment: ...wait, I'm stupid. I miscalculated the odds. I had it correct in my mind, but on paper, I assumed the list would only continue with a 25% chance, in which case it WOULD be astronomically low. Running your code confirms it when flipping the "<" to an ">".

Comment: Ah, cool. Right for the 100s  your chances of getting a list of length 35 would be `0.75**34 = 0.0000565`, or 0.00565% ... not exactly astronomical especially when computers are involved. True that `0.25 ** 34` is quite a different story!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a chance of about 0.005% to get it, you tried 30 times -> about 0.15% that this happens. You are a lucky guy:-)

Code to calculate:

```
import random

hist_data = []
for i in range(1000000):
    listy = [1]

    for _ in listy:
        if random.random() > 0.25:
            listy.append(100)
    hist_data.append(len(listy))

big_numbers = [i for i in hist_data if i >= 35]
print("Chance for >=35: %.4f%%" % (100.*len(big_numbers)/len(hist_data)))
```

Comment: Shoulda bought those lottery tickets. :)